# How do I get the correct pos tags for a sentence after noun phrase merging?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I'm trying to merge noun phrase chunks in a sentence, and then getting the pos tags for each token in the merged doc. However, for each merged span, I seem to get the pos tag of the first token in the span (which is usually DET or ADJ) instead of NOUN.

Here's the code:

```py
def noun_chunk_retokenizer(doc):
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
            retokenizer.merge(chunk)
    return doc

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe(noun_chunk_retokenizer)

query = "when is the tennis match happening?"
[(c.text,c.pos_) for c in nlp(query)]
```

This is the result I get:

```
[('when', 'ADV'),
 ('is', 'VERB'),
 ('the tennis match', 'DET'),
 ('happening', 'VERB'),
 ('?', 'PUNCT')]
```

but I'm expecting 'the tennis match' to be tagged as 'NOUN', which is how it works on the displacy demo: https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?

It seems like there should be a "standard" way to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Try adding `attrs={"POS": "NOUN"}` to the `merge` method: `retokenizer.merge(chunk, attrs={"POS": "NOUN"})`

Comment: I figured it out, nvm. merge_noun_chunks is already a built-in pipeline component that I can use directly instead of writing a function to do it. Still curious to understand how exactly this works under the hood.

Comment: Here's the link in case anyone else has the same question: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#built-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [built-in `merge_noun_chunks` component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#built-in). 
See the [*Pipeline Functions* documenation](https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_noun_chunks):

> Merge noun chunks into a single token. Also available via the string name `"merge_noun_chunks"`. After initialization, the component is typically added to the processing pipeline using [nlp.add_pipe](https://spacy.io/api/language#add_pipe).

Sample usage with your string:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('merge_noun_chunks'))
query = "when is the tennis match happening?"
[(c.text,c.pos_) for c in nlp(query)]
```

​
Output:

```
[('when', 'ADV'),
 ('is', 'VERB'),
 ('the tennis match', 'NOUN'),
 ('happening', 'VERB'),
 ('?', 'PUNCT')]
```

As for the question "how is it done in source code" please refer to [spacy Github repo](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/pipeline/functions.py#L7), `/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/pipeline/functions.py` file at Line 7:

```
def merge_noun_chunks(doc):
    """Merge noun chunks into a single token.
    doc (Doc): The Doc object.
    RETURNS (Doc): The Doc object with merged noun chunks.
    DOCS: https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_noun_chunks
    """
    if not doc.is_parsed:
        return doc
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for np in doc.noun_chunks:
            attrs = {"tag": np.root.tag, "dep": np.root.dep}
            retokenizer.merge(np, attrs=attrs)
    return doc
```